# Is it possible to disable login for dynadmin of ATG?

Tags: atg

We use dynamo administration of ATG  frequently to test the changes done to various other components. Is there any way to disable login for opening Dynamo Administration? Many times we observed that it asks the credentials multiple times. Any guesses as to why it does that and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging in, I have found a better approach. The much simpler way of disabling the authentication is by disabling authentication in AuthenticationServlet.

To acheive this `DYNAMO_HOME/localconfig/atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/AuthenticationServlet.properties` file must have the content shown below.

```
$class=atg.servlet.pipeline.BasicAuthenticationPipelineServlet
enabled=false
```

Basic Authentication Pipeline Servlet is the class that is redirecting the authentication to other components, by changing enabled=false, we can disable the authentication. Changing it to true will enable the authentication as before.

Follow this link for more information: [Disable DynAdmin authentication of Oracle Commerce](http://controlspace.info/2016/04/disable-dynadmin-auth-dev-env-oracle-commerce/)

Comment: Will it have any side effects in case we use LDAP for authentication.

Comment: I haven't given it a try, but I'm assuming that the request won't go for LDAP server as we have disabled authentication. We can enable authentication in case if that is critical. However, I meant this to be in development environment where most of our testing is done using users created locally.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it by over-riding the Authenticator and return true if a flag "allowPassThroughEnabled" is true from the configuration.

As BasicAuthenticationServlet Pipeline calls Authenticator to authenticate a user if the request comes in bearing an Authorization header with Basic authentication.

I over-rode the Authenticator component, added a boolean property

```
allowPassThroughEnabled
```

this enables/disables the authentication.

The properties file and class file look like this :

```
#/atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/Authenticator.properties
$class=com.myadminpipeline.CustomUserAuthorityAuthenticator
allowPassThroughEnabled=true
```

and the class :

```
package com.myadminpipeline;

import atg.servlet.pipeline.UserAuthorityAuthenticator;

public class CustomUserAuthorityAuthenticator extends
        UserAuthorityAuthenticator {


    private boolean allowPassThroughEnabled;

    public boolean isAllowPassThroughEnabled() {
        return allowPassThroughEnabled;
    }

    public void setAllowPassThroughEnabled(boolean allowPassThroughEnabled) {
        this.allowPassThroughEnabled = allowPassThroughEnabled;
    }

@Override
public boolean authenticate(String pUserId, String pPassword) {

    if (isAllowPassThroughEnabled()){
        return true;
    }

    return super.authenticate(pUserId, pPassword);
}

}
```

it does the job for me. you can also switch this flag true or false as per your requirement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for a good idea of overriding... I didn't know it is possible to override existing classes by making use of properties file. I will give it a try. Is there any good document available for learning about ATG apart from oracle docs?

Comment: Excellent. This worked like magic. I have created a new module which I have deployed along with DafEar.Admin and I'm successfully able to override authentication. However not awarding bounty yet just to wait and see if there are other solutions for the same problem as awarding bounty will take away the special status of featured question and reduce attention.

Comment: thanks Buddha, i have learnt mostly from the Oracle docs or on projects, though there are many good blogs available too. http://internetmarketing-readme.pricemaniacs.com/useful-atg-blogssites/

Comment: Thanks for the links @boyintello Oracle docs is a good reference material but they are not for beginners like me who are just starting out in ATG world.

Comment: Though, my dyn/admin login is disabled, I see that I'm getting this following exception in the log: [nucleusNamespace] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Unable to create class com.buddha.adminpipeline.CustomUserAuthenticator for configuration /atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/Authenticator java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.buddha.adminpipeline.CustomUserAuthenticator from [Module "deployment.EXP_JUnitModule.ear.atg_bootstrap_ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]. Do you have any clue as to what this might be?.

Comment: do you have some other properties in your properties file for the component, could you share your MANIFEST/properties file for the module? should be something with your module set up, or the build process. Don't see any other reason for ClassNotFound

Comment: Let me repeat again, my authentication skipping is working fine even withthis error. However just as a curiosity, this is what I have in my Manifest.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
ATG-Config-Path: ./config/
ATG-Required: SystemTests.base
ATG-Class-Path: ./classes/

Name: skiplist.xml
ATG-Assembler-Import-File: true

Name: mite.xml
ATG-Assembler-Import-File: true

Comment: I understood that, however your ClassNotFoundException points otherwise. when is the exception, while initializing your component, or every time you hit dyn/admin?

Comment: Nope, it is coming once and only when the server is initializing.

Comment: Just an FYI, I have found another simple approach to disable authentication. In case you need it, you can check my answer to the same question.

Answer (score 1):

So far I couldn't figure out a way to do what is needed, but I have found a workaround to avoid frequent logins by enabling lazyAuthentication. By enabling lazyAuthentication feature of ATG, the login is asked only once per session. Without this feature the login is asked after every few minutes of inactivity. In order to enable this feature do the following...

1. Navigate to $DYNAMO_HOME/localconfig/atg/dynamo
2. Create a folder named servlet if it doesn't already exist
3. Create a folder named adminpipeline inside servlet if it already doesn't exist
4. Create a properties file with the name Authenticator.properties with below content in it.

```
    $class=atg.servlet.pipeline.UserAuthorityAuthenticator
    $scope=global
    userAuthority=/atg/dynamo/security/AdminUserAuthority
    userPath=/atg/dynamo/security/User
    lazyAthentication=true
    allowedAccounts=administrators-group
    repository=/atg/dynamo/security/AdminSqlRepository
```

Comment: +1 for lazyAuthentication.... This seems like a good option but We shall wait if there are better answers.